# Replace empty lines with a Heading style with Normal style

Tags: ms-word

I'm in the process of updating a heap of manuals which for whatever reason have Heading Formats applied to them. The empty lines sometimes appear in the table of contents which is annoying the end recipients somewhat.

The documents have a mix of styles I need to replace, ie the Paragraphs in the boxes below, but I can't work out a way to find an empty line with a specific style that may or may not differ from the previous line.

[image: Styles to replace]

I'm getting the impression it's not doable but thought I'd ask here before doing it manually. The main effect is on navigation but occasionally TOC, usually when compatibility is maintained.

[image: Navigation example]